# How to Create a list of Gradient Colors list in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, colors, gradient, local

I wish to create a list of 7 gradient colors which i can apply randomly as background to a container.

```
gradientColors[rand(0,6)];
```

The list needs to be stored locally in app in seprate file.

the idea was to do some thing like below:

```
List<Color> gradientRed = Colors.amber, Colors.red;
List<Color> gradientBlue = Colors.blue, Colors.blueAccent;

List<Colors> gradientColor = [
  gradientRed, gradientBlue, ...
];
```

but i am facing following error:

```
The element type 'List<Color>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Colors'.dart(list_element_type_not_assignable)
```

plus i was trying to generate random number between the given range. but i am always get same number.

using this code inside foreach loop in flutter

```
    int min = 0;
    int max = gradientColors.length;
    var randIndex = min + (Random(1).nextInt(max - 1));
    print(randIndex);
```

what is a solution here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the list issue i had, i just removed the List type and let it be dynamic now like below:

```
List gradientColors = [
     gradientRed,
     gradientBlue,
     gradientGreen,
     gradientYellow,
     gradientPurple,
     gradientPink,
     gradientOrange,
     gradientAmber,
];
```

and for the random number on list length i used below code:

```
const int min = 0;
    int max = gradientColors.length;
    var randIndex = Random().nextInt(max);
    print(randIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your List type needs to be a list itself:

```
List<List<Colors>> gradientColor = [color gradients go here]
```

Comment: I have not yet tested this solution but was able to get around by using dyamic list type and it's working now. will definately try this as its basically forcing a type on the list. in mean while do you know the answer for random number generation in the given rang in flutter. i am tried the code which i have added after your comment in the first post. please see it and provide your inputs on the same.